# Python peewee foreign key constraint incorrectly formed

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm currently working on a python project using peewee to connect to MySQLDatabase. 
If I want to create a table using 
`database.create_tables(tables=[])` (create_table does not work) 
 I get the following error message from my logger:

> ERROR session[5924]: (1005, 'Can't create table example_database.example_table (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')

example_table is specified as:

```
class Example_Table(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    example_table2 = ForeignKeyField(Modul)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Example_Table'
```

BaseModel is defined as follows:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database
```

and database is my MySQLDatabase Object. 
The Problem is, why doesnt the foreign key constraint work and why are the tables all saved in Lowercase, but I defined them in Uppercase

If I run the program again, It creates the tables but gives me a duplicate key_name error

Version: peewee==3.0.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in peewee 3.x, you use `table_name` rather than `db_table` to explicitly declare a non-default table name.

I ran some sample code locally to give a test:

```
class User(Model):
    username = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = db
        table_name = 'UserTbl'

class Note(Model):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='notes')
    content = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = db
        table_name = 'NoteTbl'
```

I created the tables and checked the SQL output, which looks correct to me:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UserTbl` (`id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `username` TEXT NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NoteTbl` (`id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `content` TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `UserTbl` (`id`))
CREATE INDEX `note_user_id` ON `NoteTbl` (`user_id`)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you that solved my Problem with the names of the tables and now the foreign Key Constraint problem is gone too. I had the code from an older project where I use peewee==2.xx.